# Make night sky with moon

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I want to make skybox with moon (texture 2d) with shader graph and be able to modify moon radius.

Moon Texture 2d :
[image]

Comment: When you haven't accepted previous answers where volunteers here have put in work to help you (or up-voted them, once you've earned the rep to do so), it can dampen their enthusiasm to spend their time helping you further.

Comment: I did not accept it because it did not help me completely. If it helped me, I would not have needed to write another question. Note in the question that I wrote instead of a cubemap.

Comment: That's not how things work here. It's normal to accept an answer when it correctly answers the question that was asked, even if you later find your game needs something different than was asked. This does a few useful things: 1) it signals to the question filtering system that the old question is resolved, so it does not keep re-circulating to the top of the question feed for new input, 2) it rewards users who take the time to offer help, incentivizing them to keep coming to the site and keep helping you or other users, 3) it signals to future readers which solutions have been verified.

Comment: Ok I will do that.

Comment: Which is better for cubemap or texture2d performance?

Comment: If you only need one side, a texture is cheaper on memory and sampling math.

Comment: I noticed that in both of your moon shader questions, you're asking for very specific things. That's great if you know exactly what you need, but there's also benefit in including your high level outcomes to avoid XY problems. Editing to include info about what your end goal is & why/how the cubemap solution failed to meet that goal increases the chance that you'll get a solution that helps you solve your actual problem.

Comment: It did not fail, but I found that there was no need for it, as I would not benefit from it, so I decided to use a texture2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shader that does this (click for a larger version so you can read the text):

[image: Shader graph]

And the result in a Unity scene:

[image: Scene with moon]

The strategy is similar to my [previous answer with the cubemap](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/206761/39518). We'll use the object space view vector (the vector pointing from the fragment being shaded back at the camera, in the object's local space) to make it easy to control the positioning and twist of the moon image: you can rotate the skybox itself. The moon will get drawn wherever the object's local z+ axis (blue arrow on the local translation gizmo) points, extended to infinity. You can use a world space view vector to sample the starfield if you want to angle the two independently.

We use the X and Y components of the view vector as texture coordinates to look up into our moon texture. First, dividing them by our desired moon radius (so at the desired radius, the length of the XY vector becomes 1), then multiplying them by a half and adding a half to bring them into the 0-1 texture coordinate range. I also negate them in this step, because otherwise we'd draw the moon rotated 180 degrees.

I also put a conditional branch in here so we only sample the moon texture when it will contribute to the image, and skip that work for the majority of the sky.

Comment: @AhmedDyaa, may I ask why you removed the accept checkmark on this answer and the previous? If there's something about the answer that needs to be improved, please provide details in a comment or by editing your question.

Comment: How can I implement it with my used shader that I send it's picture?

Comment: Because it didn't work for me. I think I did something wrong.

Comment: I need to see what you did to try to incorporate this answer before I can help you fix it. I also need to know what specific symptoms of "not working" you observed.

Comment: I modified the question and added your solution.

Comment: A lesson in communication: the issue here is NOT that "this shader for drawing the moon does not work". The issue is "I have another part of my shader that draws a glowing halo around the moon, and it does not draw that halo in the same position as the moon texture". Note that this was not part of the text of your original question. To ensure you get help that accurately meets your needs, make sure you explicitly state ALL of those requirements in the text of your question from the beginning. This helps avoid days of back-and-forth miscommunications and wasted time.

Comment: The halo is not related to the body of the moon and has no effect on it. It follows the moon only through the moon dir, so I did not mention it.

Comment: If you want them both to be drawn in the same place, then it's related, and MUST be mentioned. You're not going to get agreement between these two things by coincidence: you have to ask for it and arrange for it to happen specifically.

Comment: No, The halo is completely independent of the Moon, except for its position. And I only need to draw moon shape (circle in the centre of halo)

Comment: "except for" means it's NOT independent. The position calculation needs to be consistent between the two. You've used my position calculation for the moon texture, then used a completely unrelated position calculation for the halo, so they're obviously not going to match in general. You need to use the same direction information for both. If you'd like to know how to do that, make sure you ask "how do I align this halo with the position where the moon is drawn?"

Comment: I'm using the same direction information for moon shape and it's halo by "Moon Direction"  you will find that in "Moon shader after add moon texture node" image in the question, and your texture use view vector so how do I align your texture with moon Direction and dot product?

Comment: You don't. One vector isn't enough information to control both where the moon is drawn and its twist (which way the 'top' of the texture points) — that's why I use the rotation of the skybox for that purpose. Again, **edit your question** to ask "how can I align this halo with the moon" and I can show you how to correct the halo to match.