# Align Cubemap OR Texture2D moon with Unity light rotation?

Tags: unity-shader-graph

I am trying to make a custom skybox shader in Unity Shadergraph. I am having difficulty implementing the solutions find [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/206753/make-moon-using-cubemap-in-shadergraph) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/206817/put-texture-on-moon-with-shadergraph).

The solutions themselves are fantastic and work as advertised; however, being new to Shadergraph, I am at a loss for how to align them with the rotation of a moon light object in my scene as opposed to the rotation of the skybox itself.

My shader currently draws the sun by getting the arccosine of the dot product between the sun's direction and the normalized view direction:

[image: A screenshot of a shadergraph group getting the position of a light's rotation]

This method does not (seemingly) integrate with the above-linked methods, as this method outputs a single value and the those methods require a Vector3 to split. If I plug the arccosine setup into the cubemap solution, I get a textureless moon (presumably because of the lack of Vector3 information):

[image: A screenshot of the first part of the moon shadergraph]
[image: The moon in game, textureless]

If I go directly from the normalized view direction node to the split node, the cubemap moon shows up beautifully, but only at the horizon (for lack of direction information).

I've tried using Rotate About Axis nodes, which does change the position of the textured cubemap moon in the sky, but not as desired.

[image: The beginning of the moon shader with rotate about axis nodes instead of the arccosine setup previously]

At this point I think I just have a fundamental lack of understanding and so my efforts to throw something at the wall that sticks are less than fruitful. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

PS. I hope it's okay to make a new post on this. I'm new to Stack Exchange and I don't have enough reputation to simply ask the clarifying question on the original post(s).